# Java Mockito: How to test when a private exception is thrown? (Not a private method)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a test that throws `HttpException` from a certain library (`com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j`). I have written a test like so:

```java
Exception exception = assertThrows(HttpException.class,
        () -> this.myApi.getInformation(date1, date2)
    );
```

For this, I have imported the `HttpException` class like so:

```java
import com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.HttpException;
```

However, doing so gives me an error message:

```
'com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.HttpException' is not public in 'com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j'. 
Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

So, even though this exception is thrown in certain conditions, I am unable to test that this exception will be thrown under those conditions. Is there any way that I can test this?

My workaround, since the private `HttpException` extends `RuntimeException`, I can test it by asserting that `RuntimeException` is thrown. However, is there a better way to test this?

Comment: Your code should probably not throw an exception defined in another library since that leaks the implementation to the caller and forces the caller to handle an exception that may change in the future.  Instead, define your own exception, catch the dependent library exception, and throw your own exception.  That should also help to simplify a unit test.

Comment: Partially agreed, but I think even if I want to catch that specific private exception in the code, I still would have to catch `RuntimeException`, since I won't be able to import `HttpException` which is private. I think any external libraries shouldn't really throw a private exception outside the library at the first place, and that it must only be used internally.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrew S. in the comments and your API shouldn't expose private exceptions:

> Your code should probably not throw an exception defined in another library since that leaks the implementation to the caller and forces the caller to handle an exception that may change in the future. Instead, define your own exception, catch the dependent library exception, and throw your own exception. That should also help to simplify a unit test.

But if you *really must* and can not change your code, there is a workaround: asserting a general exception was thrown and then asserting the canonical name of this exception:

```
Exception exception = assertThrows(
        RuntimeException.class,
        () -> this.myApi.getInformation(date1, date2));
assertEquals(
        "com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.HttpException",
        exception.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```